# How to prevent exceptions caused by updating Riverpod state during Flutter widget build?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am trying to build a Flutter application using Riverpod for state management. I have a CounterController that either increments/decrements a count (if it's of type upToSeven) or adds/subtracts 30 minutes from a DateTime (if it's of type dateTime). I want to update my Riverpod state based on this CounterController.

However, when I attempt to update the state during the widget build (in ReminderFrequencyRow), I get the following error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter_riverpod/src/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 343 pos 12: 'debugDoingBuild == false': Cannot modify providers during build.
```

Here's my code:

NotificationSettingsController

```
final hasUnsavedChangesProvider = Provider<bool>((ref) {
  return ref.watch(notificationSettingsProvider.notifier).hasUnsavedChanges;
});

class NotificationSettingsController extends StateNotifier<UserSettings> {
  NotificationSettingsController(UserSettings settings) : super(settings);

  bool hasUnsavedChanges = false;

  void updateMotivationalQuoteFrequency(int frequency) {
    state = state.copyWith(motivationalQuoteReminderFrequency: frequency);
    hasUnsavedChanges = true;
  }

  void updateMotivationalQuoteStartTime(DateTime startTime) {
    state = state.copyWith(motivationalQuoteStartTime: startTime);
    hasUnsavedChanges = true;
  }

  void updateMotivationalQuoteEndTime(DateTime endTime) {
    state = state.copyWith(motivationalQuoteEndTime: endTime);
    hasUnsavedChanges = true;
  }

  void updateGoalCheckUpReminderTime(DateTime reminderTime) {
    state = state.copyWith(goalCheckUpReminderTime: reminderTime);
    hasUnsavedChanges = true;
  }

  void updateTaskCheckUpReminderTime(DateTime reminderTime) {
    state = state.copyWith(taskCheckUpReminderTime: reminderTime);
    hasUnsavedChanges = true;
  }
}
```

CounterController:

```
enum CounterType { upToSeven, dateTime }

final counterProvider = StateNotifierProvider.family<CounterController, dynamic,
    CounterProviderParams>((ref, params) {
  return CounterController(params.type, params.startHour, params.startMinute,
      params.endHour, params.endMinute);
});

 class CounterController extends StateNotifier<dynamic> {
      final CounterType type;
      final DateTime startTime;
      final DateTime endTime;
    
      CounterController(
          this.type, int startHour, int startMinute, int endHour, int endMinute)
          : startTime = DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month,
                DateTime.now().day, startHour, startMinute),
            endTime = DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month,
                DateTime.now().day, endHour, endMinute),
            super(type == CounterType.dateTime
                ? DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month,
                    DateTime.now().day, startHour, startMinute)
                : 3) {
        if (type == CounterType.dateTime &&
            (endTime.isBefore(startTime) || endTime.isAtSameMomentAs(startTime))) {
          throw ArgumentError('End time must be later than start time');
        }
      }
    
      void increment() {
        if (type == CounterType.upToSeven && state < 7) {
          state++;
        } else if (type == CounterType.dateTime &&
            state is DateTime &&
            (state as DateTime).isBefore(endTime)) {
          state = (state as DateTime).add(Duration(minutes: 30));
        }
      }
    
      void decrement() {
        if (type == CounterType.upToSeven && state > 3) {
          state--;
        } else if (type == CounterType.dateTime &&
            state is DateTime &&
            (state as DateTime).isAfter(startTime)) {
          state = (state as DateTime).subtract(Duration(minutes: 30));
        }
      }
    }
```

CustomCounterWidget:

```
class CustomCounterWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  final CounterProviderParams params;
  final UniqueKey key;

  CustomCounterWidget({required this.params, required this.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    final counter = ref.watch(counterProvider(params));
    return Row(
      children: [
        // decrement and increment buttons and counter display...
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

ReminderFrequencyRow:

```
class ReminderFrequencyRow extends ConsumerWidget {
  final UniqueKey key;
  final CounterProviderParams params;
  final String labelText;
  final void Function(dynamic) onCounterChanged; // The callback

  ReminderFrequencyRow({
    required this.key,
    required this.params,
    required this.labelText,
    required this.onCounterChanged, // Initialize the callback
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final theme = ref.watch(themeProvider);
    final counter = ref.watch(counterProvider(params));

    // Call the callback when the counter changes
    onCounterChanged(counter);

    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Text(
          labelText,
          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
            fontSize: 16,
            color: theme.colorScheme.onTertiary,
          ),
        ),
        CustomCounterWidget(
          params: params,
          key: key,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

}

This is where the issue occurs:

```
ReminderFrequencyRow(
  key: motivationalEndKey,
  params: counterParams,
  labelText: 'End at',
  onCounterChanged: (counter) {
    if (counter is DateTime)
      ref
          .watch(notificationSettingsProvider.notifier)
          .updateMotivationalQuoteEndTime(counter);
  },
)
```

Comment: Can you try commenting `onCounterChanged(counter);`

Comment: I did and still getting the same results

Comment: build() should be idempotent, and not change any outside state during the build.  You are apparently trying to update a value in a provider.  Stop that.  Your build should be a view of the current data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is standard - you shouldn't call `ref.watch` in widget lifecycle methods and callbacks. In this case:

```
ReminderFrequencyRow(
  key: motivationalEndKey,
  params: counterParams,
  labelText: 'End at',
  onCounterChanged: (counter) {
    if (counter is DateTime)
      ref//⬇here⬇
          .read(notificationSettingsProvider.notifier)
          .updateMotivationalQuoteEndTime(counter);
  },
)
```

Also, you should think about the architecture of your application. This code is not good practice:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final theme = ref.watch(themeProvider);
    final counter = ref.watch(counterProvider(params));

    // This is wrong behavior
    onCounterChanged(counter);
```